# Unable to click send (greyed out option) on APEX wallet to deploy the contract on local blockchain using hardhat

Tags: smartcontracts, apex, hardhat

I am following the alchemy university course to deploy a escrow smart contract on a local blockchain. However my apex wallet is not able to deploy the contract. See screenshow below.

[Send button unable to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hli1.jpg)

What i should be getting instead is this screenshot.

[Correct screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHjWl.jpg)

Anyone has any idea what is causing this?